# Rails: Add multiple JSON-LD to a page in one array

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails app, I currently add single [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) structured data objects to a page using `content_for` like so:

`helpers/structured_data_helper.rb`

```rb
def local_business_json_ld(page)
  content_for(:json_ld) do
    sanitize(local_business_schema(page).to_json)
  end
end

def local_business_schema(page)
  {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'LocalBusiness',
    name: page.name,
    telephone: page.telephone,
    # etc.
  }
end
```

`views/pages/show.html.erb`

```
<% local_business_json_ld(@page) %>
```

`views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<% if content_for? :json_ld %>
  <%= tag.script(type: 'application/ld+json') { yield :json_ld } %>
<% end %>
```

This works well for **a single JSON-LD object on a page** i.e. the result is:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "Example Name",
    "telephone": "1-888 567888",
    <!-- etc. -->
  }
</script>
```

But now **I want to add multiple JSON-LD objects to the page in one array** i.e. the result I'm looking for is:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  [
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "LocalBusiness",
      "name": "Example Name",
      "telephone": "1-888 567888",
      <!-- etc. -->
    },
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "Books",
          "item": "https://example.com/books"
        },
        <!-- etc. -->
      ]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

So far this has proven difficult. I don't see how to add an array by default in the `content_for` that I can `push()` to without the formatting breaking along the way.

Any ideas how I can change my setup to achieve an array of JSON-LD objects?

Comment: How do you come up with something like this `{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "name": "Books",
          "item": "https://example.com/books"
        },
        <!-- etc. -->
      ]
    }`?

Comment: That's [JSON-LD `BreadcrumbList`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/breadcrumb#html_example), not sure what your question is?

Comment: But is it specific to your case? Or something that can be hardcoded? Do you construct it somehow?

Comment: It's just an example of some structured data, see [Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html). I do use `BreadcrumbList` and generate it, but the question is more about how to push these objects once created to an array.